# How to create AppData folder for a domain user added to a local group

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I have added a domain user into group Users using Add User wizard in Windows 7.

Unfortunatelly the folder for user data (`c:\Users\<NewUser>\AppData`) was not created.

How can I instruct Windows to create this folder with appropriate permissions and structure?

I am experiencing the same issue on Windows Server 2008 R2.

**Background**

The domain user was assigned to us as a login to Database. Since we want to use Integrated Security to connect from our ASP.NET application, we added this domain user to our web server OS and configured him as the identity of the IIS AppPool.

Now the application needs to load PFX certificate from a file, which requires R/W permissions for the folder

```
C:\Users\<NewUser>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\
```

This folder does not exist in the system and so the application fails with the following exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
    The specified network password is not correct.
```

Comment: Can't you login as the user to create this folder?

Comment: @Robert Our customer claims that they did login as the user (Windows Server 2008 R2 scenario) and that the folder was not created :(

Comment: Are you sure its not a password issue, as error suggests? I think the folder is there, its just hidden so they can probably get there via address bar rather than browsing

Comment: @Robert I am absolutely sure. The certificate is built-in, has no password, and the application was successfully deployed in different environment. The C:\Users\<NewUser> folder is not present at the server. I also managed to reproduce the same scenario at my local machine (although I did not try to login as the new user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to create the application data folder (and contents) is for the user to log in.

If the user has logged in, but `c:\Users\xxx\AppData` was not created, the most likely reason is that the application data folder has been redirected by group policy.

In this scenario, your customer probably just needs to find the user's RSA folder (which is probably sitting on a file server somewhere) and make a copy of it in the location your software is expecting.